# User can't see .doc attachments in outlook/OWA from one specific user

Tags: exchange, outlook

We have Exchange 2013 in our domain, and one user cannot see **.doc** attached files from another specific user. If I send him **.doc** attached files, he sees it just fine. In the sender's outlook, the mail displayed with attachments.
 I've tried to search through google but there is an only similar problem related to executable extensions such as **.exe, .vbs,** and etc, but **.doc** is not executable and in the past, this user didn't have such problem. And by saying "he can't see attachments" I mean he really can't, there is just a usual mail without any attachment icons.

I've also checked that sender sends the mail in HTML format.

Have someone encountered such a problem?

P.S 
Sorry if I made some mistakes, English isn't my native language.

Comment: Have you checked the transport rules which may cause the issue? 
You can try to enable the pipeline tracing for the user, view the message snapshot files and check which step is wrong. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/pipeline-tracing-exchange-2013-help
Also, refer to this : https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000728.htm

Comment: @joyceshen, thanks for the answer, I'll definitely check those articles today later!